# One API proxy calling two different target endpoints

Tags: apigee

i have just started working with Apigee.
I want to create one API proxy which will call two target endpoints based on 'if' condition.
i have created an API and added resources to it but the problem is in this case i am getting two API's .
If thetype='abc' target point should be target1
if thetype='xyz' target point should be target2
Can anyone please tell me how to proceed with it ?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585111/3182611). The details of finding the RouteRules is listed there. The [ProxyEndpoint documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/api-proxy-configuration-reference#-a-name-proxyendpoint-a-proxyendpoint) will also be helpful.

You can accomplish what you are attempting using this code:

```
<RouteRule name="routeToTarget1">
    <Condition>thetype == "abc"</Condition>
    <TargetEndpoint>target1</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="routeToTarget2">
    <Condition>thetype == "xyz"</Condition>
    <TargetEndpoint>target2</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

These RouteRules will be evaluated in order.

Note that you probably want the bottom RouteRule to have no condition, which means it will always match. What happens when thetype does not equal "abc" or "xyz"? Assuming target1 is the default, your code would look like this:

```
<RouteRule name="routeToTarget2">
    <Condition>thetype == "xyz"</Condition>
    <TargetEndpoint>target2</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="routeToTarget1">
    <TargetEndpoint>target1</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.
I tried with the code you have sent but it's throwing me an error::
Error while Uploading file for API vmife.
messaging.config.beans.InvalidBundle. Errors:[Entity : Proxy, Target Not Found: http://url../../;]

Comment: 'thetype' here is one column in table . Here , i am creating a Proxy API for two target endpoints. Now these target endpoints are two different API's . I have a filter condition for one of the API's which is working fine in the browser (https://url?$filter=thtype eq 123)
Now in my condition i am saying <condition>thetype==123</condition> but it is not working.

Comment: How are you populating the "thetype" variable? I'm sure you know, but request.queryparam.$filter (which can be accessed in a JavaScript policy by using context.getVariable("request.queryparam.$filter")) will have the value "thtype eq 123" (using your example in the comment above). You'll need to parse that string to get the value 123.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the API Proxy Editor UI, then you can do the following:

(1) Choose **New** / **New Resource** from the API Proxy Editor toolbar.

You will then see this:
[image]

(2) For the input field, *Optional Target URL*, enter the target URL that corresponds to that resource.

This tool will then generate both a conditional flow for that resource to which you can optionally attach resource-specific policies.

This tool will also add the needed route rule, and your generated XML will look like this:

```
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <RouteRule name="Resource-1">
        <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/someResource&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
        <HTTPTargetConnection>
            <URL>http://myAlternateEndpoint</URL>
        </HTTPTargetConnection>
    </RouteRule>
    ....
```

Comment: Hello Randy,this method will give me two API's but i want only one API  for two target endpoints. i don't want two resources.

Answer (score 0):

on Mike Dunker answer I want to edit one more thing
you have to add one more xml file inside /apiproxy/targets/ folder and the name of the file will be target2.xml and target1.xml and inside file name of targetendpoint :  
target2 or target1
and new xml file content same as default.xml with changes that you want to add in new targetEndPoints