# One Apigee Api Proxy with a different target endpoint for each environment

Tags: api, rest, environment-variables, backend, apigee

I am an Apigee beginner. We are doing a migration to Apigee.

We have our environments in our host names, for example:

```
something.int.other.thing.co.uk
something.test.other.thing.co.uk
something.stage.other.thing.co.uk
something.prod.other.thing.co.uk
```

I would like to be able to map them to the 4 environments of the apigee api proxy itself, respectively **int, test, stage, prod**.

I currently have one Rest resource for them, for example: `/resource`

Basically I would like the apigee api proxy with one rest resource, to map to 4 different target endpoints, depending on the environment.

So far I have tried to do it from the UI and have not been able to do so.

I have been going through the documentation and I have found these so far:

- According to this it should be possible:
  "An API proxy can contain zero or more TargetEndpoints." (TargetEndpoint section)

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/api-proxy-configuration-reference

- According to these, you can make routerules to the proxy endpoint, but I have not been able to implement it to the targetendpoint:

[Create a New Endpoint on an existing API Proxy with "No Target Endpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569963/create-a-new-endpoint-on-an-existing-api-proxy-with-no-target-endpoint/22585111#22585111)

[One API proxy calling two different target endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783986/one-api-proxy-calling-two-different-target-endpoints/22791169#22791169)

I also tried doing something along the lines of this, for TargetEndpoint, where I tested for the environment name, but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
    <Description/>
    <Flows/>
    <PreFlow name="PreFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PreFlow>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <URL>something.int.other.thing.co.uk</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
    <RouteRule name="int">
        <Condition>environment.name == "int"</Condition>
        <TargetEndpoint>something.int.other.thing.co.uk</TargetEndpoint>
    </RouteRule>
    <RouteRule name="test">
        <Condition>environment.name == "test"</Condition>
        <TargetEndpoint>something.test.other.thing.co.uk/</TargetEndpoint>
    </RouteRule>
    <RouteRule name="stage">
        <Condition>environment.name == "stage"</Condition>
        <TargetEndpoint>something.stage.other.thing.co.uk/</TargetEndpoint>
    </RouteRule>
    <RouteRule name="prod">
        <Condition>environment.name == "prod"</Condition>
        <TargetEndpoint>something.prod.other.thing.co.uk</TargetEndpoint>
    </RouteRule>
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

So is this possible?

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: Apigee Target Servers, see the selected solution comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apigee supports the concept of [Target Servers](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/load-balancing-across-backend-servers) -which abstracts the backend host from the proxies and also provides load balancing. Same target servers can be configured to point to different host for each environment (this concept is built in to Apigee already).

Take a look, this should help.

Srikanth

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
I saw these:
    http://apigee.com/docs/api/api_methods/232-create-a-targetserver
    http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/load-balancing-across-backend-servers
**1)**  In our conpany there are a lot of teams, and we all as far as I know currently under the same organisation. If I create the target servers and health monitors to an example url such as: 
https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org_name}/environments/test/targetservers
doesn't this mean that other teams will have access to them, and can possibly change their configuration, or delete them?

Comment: **2)** Our company is also issuing an SSL Certificate for Apigee, will this need to be taken into consideration when setting up target servers. If so, in what way?

Comment: **3)** From the links above I can't make out how to do the HealthMonitor configuration. To which urls do you curl the LoadBalancer and HealthMonitor configuration?

Answer (score 2):

LoadBalancer and TargetServer settings go in the TargetEndpoint definition, specifically in the HTTPTargetConnection element.

Check the example here:

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/load-balancing-across-backend-servers

If you do want to curl a TargetEndpoint definition to your API proxy, have a look at the following sample script to see working API calls:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/blob/master/tools/proxy_gen.sh

This script shows you how to create an API proxy and update ProxyEndpoint and TargetEndpoints via API calls.