# How do I call 2 endpoints with one proxy in Apigee?

Tags: javascript, apigee

Hi I am trying to call two different endpoints via one proxy here.

1st endpoint: basically its the java-script I coded into the .js file
2nd endpoint: this is an endpoint where I have to send the request to a third-party URL and get the response and return.

So I want to send a parameter in my query string like this:

```
http://[url to my apigee proxy]/endpoint?stub=true
```

If this is the url then it should go to my JavaScript code. If this is the url:

```
http://[url to my apigee proxy]/endpoint?stub=false
```

Then it should go to a third party url. I have already looked and tried to implement this;
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783986/one-api-proxy-calling-two-different-target-endpoints` but it's not working for me.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image: behavior]

Comment: The link you have pasted is the answer. Can you please elaborate the issue you are facing with that approach?

Comment: Does it always route to target1 ? what is behaviour you see?

Comment: hi @Srikant this is what i did but it does not worked for me:
`<RouteRule name="routeToTarget2">
    <Condition>thetype == "xyz"</Condition>
    <TargetEndpoint>target2</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="routeToTarget1">
    <TargetEndpoint>target1</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>`

Comment: hi @Srikanth i have just added a screenshot of my apigee UI

Comment: ![<img src="http://postimg.org/image/ldjuf9kg3/" />](http://postimg.org/image/ldjuf9kg3/).

Answer (score 0):

Your missing target endpoints. Please add [target endpoint xml](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/api-proxy-configuration-reference#TargetEndpoint%20Configuration). Also take look at [samples](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/using-samples) which will help you along side documentation.

Comment: I have tried adding target endpoint.xml but it doesn't work at all